# Int на разных телефонах

Tags: ios, swift

Потихоньку изучаю Swift и после урока по типам возник вопрос относительно Int. Написано, что для устройств с 32 битным процессором Int от -2147483648 до 2147483647. А для 64 битных от -9223372036854775808 до 9223372036854775807. Собственно вопрос один, но с подвопросами:

1. Как правильно его использовать?

1.1 Что произойдёт если в результате каких-либо расчетов будет получено число больше 2147483647 на устройстве с 32 битным процессором? Число-то не особо большое.

1.2 Если числа гарантированно будут в пределах от -2147483648 до 2147483647, имеет ли смысл, что на 64 битных будут такие большие пределы? Там же вроде что-то связано с выделением памяти, не будет ли оно больше ресурсов требовать/медленнее работать?

Comment: я думаю что использовать надо как-будто `int 32 бита`, если надо больше, то использовать `long long` дальше - длинку. Это надёжнее. Скорость работы будет примерно одинаковой (процессор всё равно его обработает за 1 такт). Если нужно фиксировать размер то лучше использовать что-то типо uint32 и так далее...

Comment: @pavel Вот только в Swift нет long. С-шные Clong и CLongLong по сути и являются теми же Int и Int64. Вопрос конечно глубокий, но судя по официальной документации, где советуют особо не заморачиваться с выбором, а использовать просто Int, то в большинстве стандартных задач это ни на что не повлияет. (касательно 1 и 1.2)

Answer (score 1):

Если в результате каких-либо расчетов будет получено число больше или меньше, то произойдет следующее. Все биты, с индексом больше 32 будут отброшены. Т.е. число примет другое значение.

***Пример 1***:

`x = 2147483647;`

В битовом выражении это
`1111111111111111111111111111111`

Если прибавить к нему 1, по идее должно быть так:

`2147483647 + 1 = 2147483648`

Однако на практике мы получим в битовом выражении число `10000000000000000000000000000000`

Если это тип int, то это число будет иметь значение `-2147483648`

Т.е. получим `2147483647 + 1 = -2147483648`

***Пример 2***:

```
x = 2147483647;
y = 1000;
```

Если умножить `x * y`, по идее должно быть так:

`2147483647 * 1000 = 2147483647000`

На практике мы получим в битовом выражении число `11111001111111111111111111111110000011000`

Если это тип int, то все что больше 32 знаков (начало справа) обрезается и получаем:
`11111111111111111111110000011000`

это число будет иметь значение `-1000`

Т.е. получим `2147483647 * 1000 = -1000`

***О выделении памяти:***

32 бита это 4 байта, 64 бита это 8 байт. Вывод - будет требовать больше ресурсов и как следствие будет выполняться медленнее. Но т.к. оперативная память исчисляется мегабайтами (миллионами байт) а процесс гигагерцами (миллиардами операций в секунду), то замедление работы не будет заметно. Т.е. этим можно пренебречь.

Comment: Спасибо за теорию, все логично и помогает понять как работает. Но на практике когда пишу var test = 2147483647; test += 1 и выбираю 4s/5, то сразу подчеркивает красным. А когда остальные - ничего не подчеркивает.

Comment: Используй тип Double если надо оперировать большими числами

Comment: Проблема не в оперировании большими числами, а понять, есть ли смысл его использовать, пока не перестанут поддерживаться 32 битные версии.

Comment: А у тебя числа принимают такие большие значения ?